# Handling an undefined response from react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am trying to figure out how to handle errors properly.  I have a simple function that makes a request to my backend

```
export async function fetchUser() {
    const userID = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('userID')
    const { data } = await axios.get(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}?userID=${userID}`
    )
    return data
}
```

Then within my home page component, I am using react query to trigger the above

```
const Home = () => {
    const { isLoading, isSuccess, error, isError, data } = useQuery(
        'user',
        fetchUser
    )

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <>
                <ResponseBlock message="Loading data..." />
            </>
        )
    }

    if (error) {
        return (
            <>
                <ResponseBlock message={error.response.data.message} />
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

The trouble seems to be with the error block.  Say I do not switch on my backend, I get displayed a react error stating cannot read property data of undefined.

The problem is, if I do something like the following

```
if (error && error.response.data !== undefined) {
    return (
        <>
            <ResponseBlock message={error.response.data.message} />
        </>
    )
}
```

It still hits the ResponseBlock and gives me the same error.  So what would be the best way to handle an undefined error response from the server?

Thanks

Comment: what does the structure of `error` looks like in your case? I believe the structure isn't what you think it is, [this](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-functions#handling-and-throwing-errors) might be helpful. In any case, you can use optional chaining.

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional chaining to fix this

```
if (error?.response?.data?.message) {
    return (
        <>
            <ResponseBlock message={error.response.data.message} />
        </>
    )
}
```